# Throw an exception from a singleton initializer

Tags: swift, swift3, singleton

I have a singleton that manages a set of data. If for some reason that data is unavailable I'd like the creation of the singleton to fail by throwing an exception. The compiler isn't a fan of marking the getter with `throws` NOTE: I realize I could handle this other ways but now I'm curious if it's even possible.

```
class Foo {
  class var `default`: Foo {
    let instance = Foo()

    return instance
  }

  private init() throws {
    // Throw if unable to load required data...
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your task is perfect for `Failable Initializers` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: I agree that is one way to go but in this specific case it would be much better to have the exception bubble up so that the failure can be handled by a higher level in the application. I also don't want to have to use `if let` every time I call `Foo.default`.

Comment: Maybe you can make `default` a function, and than `throw` error by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this(code from my playground), downside every call of your singleton will have to be done with try.

```html
enum FooError : Error {
  case RuntimeError(String)
}

class Foo {
  static func defaultFoo() throws -> Foo {
    if let instance = Foo("Success") {
      return instance
    } else {
      throw FooError.RuntimeError("Singleton is not created")
    }
  }

  private init?(_ parameter: String?) {
    if let _ = parameter {
      print("Init Succeded")
    } else {
      print("Init failed")
      return nil;
    }
  }
}

try Foo.defaultFoo()
```

Comment: Sry have to use "answer" to have proper formatting, otherwise code was unreadable.

Comment: Thanks @NSDmitry. Since you can't throw from a property getter I think this is the closest I can get.

Comment: Is it a singleton? For example, if the instance is created, will the above code make sure the next call to 'defaultFoo()' won't create a new instance of Foo?